# In WInUI 3 how can I pass ViewModel from a Page that has a UserControl

Tags: xaml, mvvm, user-controls, winui-3

In a WinUI 3 application, using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.

All ViewModels are created by a DI container.

The parent Page has a ViewModel and contains a child UserControl that also has a ViewModel.

Right now the UserControl DataContext is bound to the ViewModel like this:

```
<controls:AddEditControl x:Name="AddEditControl"
                                                     DataContext="{x:Bind ViewModel.UserDetailsViewModel}" />
```

What I tried to set ViewModel like this:

```
 public sealed partial class AddEditControl : UserControl
{
    public UserDetailsViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get;
    }

    public AddEditControl()
    {
        ViewModel = App.GetService<UserDetailsViewModel>();
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

The issue is that setting a ViewModel in a code behind of the UserControl the same way its set in Page is not binding properly.

The goal is to be able to use the same x:Bind markup in the UserControl as in the Page.

```
<Page x:Class="SearchUserPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:controls="using:CSA2.Controls"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      xmlns:converters="using:CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Converters"
      xmlns:ctkControls="using:CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Controls"
      xmlns:customConverters="using:CSA2.Converters"
      xmlns:i="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
      xmlns:ic="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
      mc:Ignorable="d"
      Margin="-40">
    <Page.Resources>
        
    </Page.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="ContentArea">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border Grid.Row="0"
                Margin="500 -78 60 0">
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
        <Grid x:Name="GridPanel"
              Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="{x:Bind ViewModel.UserDetailsRowHeight, Mode=OneWay}"
                               MinHeight="40" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Row="0"
                  Margin="{StaticResource NavigationViewPageContentMargin}">
          
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Row="1"
                  Margin="{StaticResource NavigationViewPageContentMargin}">
          
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Row="2"
                  Background="#FAFAFA">
                <TabView IsAddTabButtonVisible="False"
                         Background="#CCC">
                    <TabView.TabItems>
                        <TabViewItem x:Uid="UserDetailsTab"
                                     IsClosable="False">
                            <controls:AddEditControl x:Name="AddEditControl"
                                                     DataContext="{x:Bind ViewModel.UserDetailsViewModel}" />
                        </TabViewItem>
                        <TabViewItem Header="History"
                                     IsClosable="False">
                            <TextBlock Text="User History"
                                       Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}"
                                       Margin="10" />
                        </TabViewItem>                     
                    </TabView.TabItems>
                </TabView>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

```
<UserControl x:Class="Controls.AddEditControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="using:Controls"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:i="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
             xmlns:ic="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
             xmlns:converters="using:CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Converters"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <UserControl.Resources>
    </UserControl.Resources>
        <Grid Margin="{StaticResource NavigationViewPageContentMargin}"
              Padding="0 0 0 40">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid Row="0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="7*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ToggleButton Grid.Column="0"
                              Command="{Binding EditUserCommand,Mode=TwoWay}"
                              IsChecked="{Binding IsEditButtonChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"
                              Margin="10"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                              Style="{ThemeResource DefaultToggleButtonStyle}"
                              Visibility="{Binding IsEditVisible, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Viewbox Style="{StaticResource ButtonIcon}">
                            <SymbolIcon Symbol="Edit" />
                        </Viewbox>
                        <TextBlock x:Uid="EditButton" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </ToggleButton>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                            Margin="10 0"
                            Visibility="{Binding IsUserSelected, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
                    <Button Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"
                            Style="{ThemeResource DefaultButtonStyle}"
                            Margin="10 0">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Viewbox Style="{StaticResource ButtonIcon}">
                                <SymbolIcon Symbol="Save" />
                            </Viewbox>
                            <TextBlock x:Uid="SaveButton" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Button>
                    <Button Command="{Binding ResetCommand}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Viewbox Style="{StaticResource ButtonIcon}">
                                <SymbolIcon Symbol="Undo" />
                            </Viewbox>
                            <TextBlock x:Uid="ResetButton" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1"
                            Margin="10"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            Visibility="{Binding IsUserSelected, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
                    <TextBlock x:Uid="UserFunctionsText"
                               Style="{StaticResource DetailSubTitleStyle}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
             <Grid Row="1"
                  Grid.Column="0"
                  Visibility="{Binding IsUserSelected, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="7*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid Grid.Column="0"
                      Margin="10">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />                    
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="8*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.Resources>
                    </Grid.Resources>
                    <TextBlock x:Uid="UserIdText"
                               Grid.Row="0"
                               Grid.Column="0"
                               Style="{StaticResource EditForm_TextBlock}"
                               Visibility="{Binding IsCreateNewUser, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource InverseBoolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                    <TextBox x:Uid="UserIdText"
                             Grid.Row="0"
                             Grid.Column="1"
                             IsReadOnly="True"
                             Text="{Binding UserId, Mode=TwoWay}"
                             Style="{StaticResource EditForm_TextBox_ReadOnly}"
                             Visibility="{Binding IsCreateNewUser, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource InverseBoolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                    <TextBlock x:Uid="UserNameText"
                               Grid.Row="1"
                               Grid.Column="0"
                               Style="{StaticResource EditForm_TextBlock}" />
                    <TextBox x:Uid="UserNameNullText"
                             Grid.Row="1"
                             Grid.Column="1"
                             IsReadOnly="True"
                             Text="{Binding UserName, Mode=TwoWay}"
                             Style="{StaticResource EditForm_TextBox_ReadOnly}" />
                    <TextBlock x:Uid="UserEmailText"
                               Grid.Row="2"
                               Grid.Column="0"
                               Style="{StaticResource EditForm_TextBlock}" />
                    <TextBox x:Uid="UserEmailNullText"
                             Grid.Row="2"
                             Grid.Column="1"
                             IsReadOnly="True"
                             Text="{Binding UserEmail, Mode=TwoWay}"
                             Style="{StaticResource EditForm_TextBox_ReadOnly}" />
                    <TextBlock x:Uid="UserDepartmentText"
                               Grid.Row="3"
                               Grid.Column="0"
                               Style="{StaticResource EditForm_TextBlock}" />
                    <ComboBox Grid.Row="3"
                              Grid.Column="1"
                              Visibility="{Binding ReadOnlyMode, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource InverseBoolToVisibilityConverter}}"
                              IsEditable="False"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                              MaxDropDownHeight="180"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding UserDepartments}"
                              SelectedItem="{Binding UserDepartment, Mode=TwoWay}"
                              Style="{StaticResource EditForm_ComboBox}" />
                    <TextBox x:Uid="UserDepartmentNullText"
                             Grid.Row="3"
                             Grid.Column="1"
                             Visibility="{Binding ReadOnlyMode, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"
                             IsReadOnly="{Binding ReadOnlyMode, Mode=TwoWay}"
                             Text="{Binding UserDepartment, Mode=TwoWay}"
                             Style="{StaticResource EditForm_TextBox}" />
                    <TextBlock x:Uid="UserStatusText"
                               Grid.Row="4"
                               Grid.Column="0"
                               Style="{StaticResource EditForm_TextBlock}" />
                    <ComboBox Grid.Row="4"
                              Grid.Column="1"
                              Visibility="{Binding ReadOnlyMode,Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource InverseBoolToVisibilityConverter}}"
                              IsEditable="False"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                              MaxDropDownHeight="180"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding UserStatus}"
                              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUserStatus, Mode=TwoWay}"
                              Style="{StaticResource EditForm_ComboBox}" />
                    <TextBox Grid.Row="4"
                             Grid.Column="1"
                             Visibility="{Binding ReadOnlyMode, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"
                             IsReadOnly="{Binding ReadOnlyMode, Mode=TwoWay}"
                             Text="{Binding SelectedUserStatus, Mode=TwoWay}"
                             Style="{StaticResource EditForm_TextBox}" />
                    <TextBlock x:Uid="UserRoleText"
                               Grid.Row="5"
                               Grid.Column="0"
                               Style="{StaticResource EditForm_TextBlock}" />
                    <ComboBox x:Name="UserRoles"
                              Grid.Row="5"
                              Grid.Column="1"
                              Visibility="{Binding ReadOnlyMode,Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource InverseBoolToVisibilityConverter}}"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                              MaxDropDownHeight="180"
                              IsEditable="False"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding UserRoles}"
                              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUserRole, Mode=TwoWay}"
                              Style="{StaticResource EditForm_ComboBox}">
                        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <ic:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectionChanged">
                                <ic:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectedItemCommand}"
                                                        CommandParameter="{x:Bind UserRoles.SelectedItem,Mode=OneWay}" />
                            </ic:EventTriggerBehavior>
                        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    </ComboBox>
                    <TextBox Grid.Row="5"
                             Grid.Column="1"
                             Visibility="{Binding ReadOnlyMode, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"
                             IsReadOnly="{Binding ReadOnlyMode, Mode=TwoWay}"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                             Text="{Binding SelectedUserRole, Mode=TwoWay}"
                             Style="{StaticResource EditForm_TextBox}" />                   
                </Grid>
                <Grid Grid.Column="1"
                      Margin="10">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Row="2"
                  Visibility="{Binding IsEditButtonChecked, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="7*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                            Margin="10 -50 10 0"
                            Visibility="{Binding IsUserSelected, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
                    <Button Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"
                            Style="{ThemeResource DefaultButtonStyle}"
                            Margin="10 0">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Viewbox Style="{StaticResource ButtonIcon}">
                                <SymbolIcon Symbol="Save" />
                            </Viewbox>
                            <TextBlock x:Uid="SaveButton" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Button>
                    <Button Command="{Binding ResetCommand}"
                            Style="{ThemeResource DefaultButtonStyle}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Viewbox Style="{StaticResource ButtonIcon}">
                                <SymbolIcon Symbol="Undo" />
                            </Viewbox>
                            <TextBlock x:Uid="ResetButton" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

```
using CSA2.ViewModels;

// To learn more about WinUI, the WinUI project structure,
// and more about our project templates, see: http://aka.ms/winui-project-info.

namespace CSA2.Views;
/// <summary>
/// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
/// </summary>
public sealed partial class SearchUserPage : Page
{
    public SearchUserViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get;
    }

    public SearchUserPage()
    {
        ViewModel = App.GetService<SearchUserViewModel>();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Reducing your code helps help you.

Comment: "The issue is that setting a ViewModel in a code behind of the UserControl the same way its set in Page is not binding properly." How so? What is happening and what did you expect instead?